# Opening an URL from default browser crashes the application

Tags: java, javafx, browser, desktop

I have a GUI application written in JavaFX 14 (not the XML one). I currently have three lists that are connected each to a different custom class, in whom exists an ObservableList which updates the ListViews. I have three. Upon doubleclicking on an element of the first ListView, which also contains URLs, I want to open said URL inside the default browser, no matter the OS (I'm programming on Ubuntu 20.04, and this app will be used on W10 too).

```
        listSquads.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(event.getClickCount()==2) {
                try {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(bot.getSquadHandler().extractURL(listSquads.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())));
                        }       
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the code. The bot is a custom TwitchBot object, based on pIRCbot libraries. The squadHandler mentioned in the getter method is said custom class. Extract URL is a method that, as the name would suggest, extracts the exact URL given a string as input - this part works, as it's called upon in other parts of the code and works correctly, and I've also tested it.

However, upon double clicking on any given element of the ViewList, the app freezes to then crash a few seconds later. Why could that be? Is there a way to open the browser no matter the OS?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What specifically do you mean by “crash”? The preferred way to open a URL in JavaFX is via the [`HostServices.showDocument(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String)) method. You can get the `HostServices` instance from the `Application` instance, which can make it a bit awkward to use as you’ll probably want to do this in some other class, which means passing the `HostServices` instance around the application.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing :O It worked perfectly, thank you! :)